# Eclipse modeling tool, define a class as a type for an attribut

Tags: eclipse, diagram, emf, ecore

I try to make a model on eclipse modelling tool and I have in the model a class that use an other class as a type for an attribute.
I have made the class definition but I can't find the way to connect them together.
I have also made the definition for a method with a parameter with the same class type, but there I've no trouble. The class I use as a Type is in the combo box.
How should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to create an EMF metamodel, and are using a graphical editor, and try to connect EClasses.

Basically, EMF EClasses can have two kinds of features: EAttributes and EReferences. EAttributes can refer to Java types, like integer or string; while EReferences are used to connect EClasses. In other words, you cannot have an EAttribute refer to another type you added to the diagram; instead you have to create a reference between them.

Comment: Thanks for answering, it's right that I'm working with the graphical editor. I guess I have to do it with the containment  property = true. I have a further question : How to manage the visibility of the attributes. I'm supposed to use a static one and I founded any mention of a way to do it in tutorial.

Comment: EMF does not allow you to model static attributes. Basically, it is not considered a good practice in metamodels.